# Mail() function line breaks not working with recent PHP5.6 update and how to add additional $body content

Tags: php, mysql, forms, email, pdo

First I updated to PHP5.6 so my old code is not secure like PDO is and email formatting won't do line breaks anymore. I'm now using POD prepared statement (safer) to insert user submitted contact form info into db and then sending them a conformation email. Using $body = "blah, blah, blah..." I'm able to add some content. But how do I include the actual user submitted message as well so they have a copy of it?

Thanks in advance for your expert advice.

Here is my updated code based on Terry's contributions:

```
                //send email to user
        $to = $_POST['email'];
        $subject = "We received your message!";
        $body = "<p><img style='width:15%;' src='http://example.com/img/example_logo.png' alt='logo' /></p>";
        $body .= '<p>Hello '.$_POST['name'].'</p>';
        $body .= "<p>Thank you for reaching out to us. We value your opinions, concerns, suggestions, and are here to help you have the best experience.</p>";
        $body .= "<p>We will review your message (see below), and get back to you as soon as possible.</p>";
        $body .= "<p>Thank you, Team Example</p>";
        $body .= '<p>Your message: '.$_POST['message'].'</p>';


        $mail = new Mail();
        $mail->setFrom(SITEEMAIL);
        $mail->addAddress($to);
        $mail->subject($subject);
        $mail->body($body);
        $mail->send();


        //send email to admin
        $to = "admin@example.com";
        $subject = "A user has sent a message!";
        $body = "<p>A user has sent a message!</p>";
        $body .= '<p>From: '.$_POST['name'].'</p>';
        $body .= '<p>User Email: '.$_POST['email'].'</p>';
        $body .= '<p>User Message: '.$_POST['message'].'</p>';


        $mail = new Mail();
        $mail->setFrom('email');
        $mail->addAddress($to);
        $mail->subject($subject);
        $mail->body($body);
        $mail->send();
```

This works well :) The only thing left unresolved is I'm getting "SITETITLE" as site name in mail sent to admin and with mail sent to user I get "noreply". In both cases I'd like to have my domain name show instead. Any further suggestions anyone (Terry?)

I found where to fix the SITETITLE, it was in my db connection config file.
Here is an example:

```
   define('SITEEMAIL','noreply@example.com');
   define('SITETITLE','YOUR SITE NAME HERE | OTHER STUFF IF YOU LIKE');
```

I changed in my mail() function, both $mail->setFrom(SITEEMAIL); and $mail->setFrom('email'); to $mail->setFrom(SITETILE); Now all works great!

Comment: Which part of the code is not working? Your question is a little vague about that: do you mean that the PHP `mail()` function is not working?

Comment: Thanks Terry for your reply. Yes the Mail () function is my concern and it is sending the mail to user but I can't seem to figure out how to add (include) the message they sent me in with the auto reply I send them, so they have it for their records. Just below where is says "Thank you" in the $body I tried adding something like $_POST['message'] though got error and can't seem to find any documentation or examples on how to do that. I also am looking to convert the admin email to the same mail() function as the user version, but not clear on that either.

Comment: You are not appending the message to the body you are sending. What about using `$body .= '<p>'.$_POST['message'].'</p>'`? That will concatenate their message to the mail body you are sending.

Comment: That works :) But using this same technique to add the user name at the beginning of the $body does not. e.g. $body .= '<p>Hello '.$_POST['name'].',</p>' Do you have any suggestion for that? Thanks

Comment: `.=` in PHP is the equivalent of `+=` in JS. So you have to use `$body = ...` the first time, and then `$body .= ...` thereafter.

Comment: I think I have it working now thanks to your contributions Terry :) I hope it's not a hack the way I did it??? I edited the code above to reflect my changes to send to both the user and admin. I'm still wondering how to fix the "SITETITLE "and "noreply" issue I noted above.